# Stacking PHP 5.3 ternary operators - is it safe?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I am aware of the several caveats with chaining the `expr ? var1 : var2` code.

I tried stacking the PHP 5.3 `?:` operator though, and it seems to be working fine in a multiple fallback scenario:

```
php > $a=$b=0;
php > $c=5;
php > echo $a ?: $b ?: $c;
5
php > $b=2;
php > echo $a ?: $b ?: $c;
2
php > $a=1;
php > echo $a ?: $b ?: $c;
1
```

In the above example, I set a chain of fallback values, and the returned value is (as expected) the leftmost non-zero one.

Is there any case that I'm not contemlating and that might be leading to unexpected results?

Comment: Just make sure you put any expression operands in parentheses.  `$a ?: $b + 1 ?: 3` is a bit of a pain to someone who's not intimately familiar with operator precedence and associativity, and IMO it's cattle-prod-worthy in any case.

Comment: My only comment is to note the lack of parentheses... see below :)

Comment: if you use brackets it should be quite clear to read & change for humans AND php.

Comment: beware of making code short and concise at the expense of readability and maintainability.

Comment: In a more complex scenario, parentheses are definitely helpful for readability and preventing human error. But since this example is parsed linearly left to right, I don't see a big improvement from using them. Anyway, that's up to the developer's style and team relationships...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no :)

Have a read of this about Ternary ops: 
http://www.mcgarvie.net/2013/02/27/programming/php-shorthand-if-notation-or-the-ternary-operator/

It has some good examples of how to use and how NOT to use them!

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers